# Jacobi Method Outputting Wrong Eigenvalues

Tags: python, linear-algebra

I am working on creating an eigenvalue calculator using the Jacobi method and it runs without errors. However, it does not find the correct eigenvalues nor does it find the correct eigenvectors. For some reason, I always get eigenvalues of 0. I think it may not be saving the matrix I input for MatrixA.
(Link to Jacobi method in case you are not familiar: http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e176/lectures/ch1/node1.html)

```
import numpy as np
import bettertimeit as time
import matplotlib as plt

def Jacobi(A):
    n     = A.shape[0]            # matrix size #columns = #lines
    maxit = 100                   # maximum number of iterations
    eps   = 1.0e-15               # accuracy goal
    pi    = np.pi
    info  = 0                     # return flag
    ev    = np.zeros(n,float)     # initialize eigenvalues
    U     = np.zeros((n,n),float) # initialize eigenvector
    for i in range(0,n): U[i,i] = 1.0

    for t in range(0,maxit):
         s = 0    # compute sum of off-diagonal elements in A(i,j)
         for i in range(0,n): s = s + np.sum(np.abs(A[i,(i+1):n]))
         if (s < eps): # diagonal form reached
              info = t
              for i in range(0,n):ev[i] = A[i,i]
              break
         else:
              limit = s/(n*(n-1)/2.0)       # average value of off-diagonal elements
              for i in range(0,n-1):       # loop over lines of matrix
                   for j in range(i+1,n):  # loop over columns of matrix
                       if (np.abs(A[i,j]) > limit):      # determine (ij) such that |A(i,j)| larger than average
                                                         # value of off-diagonal elements
                           denom = A[i,i] - A[j,j]       # denominator of Eq. (3.61)
                           if (np.abs(denom) < eps): phi = pi/4         # Eq. (3.62)
                           else: phi = 0.5*np.arctan(2.0*A[i,j]/denom)  # Eq. (3.61)
                           si = np.sin(phi)
                           co = np.cos(phi)
                           for k in range(i+1,j):
                               store  = A[i,k]
                               A[i,k] = A[i,k]*co + A[k,j]*si  # Eq. (3.56)
                               A[k,j] = A[k,j]*co - store *si  # Eq. (3.57)
                           for k in range(j+1,n):
                               store  = A[i,k]
                               A[i,k] = A[i,k]*co + A[j,k]*si  # Eq. (3.56)
                               A[j,k] = A[j,k]*co - store *si  # Eq. (3.57)
                           for k in range(0,i):
                               store  = A[k,i]
                               A[k,i] = A[k,i]*co + A[k,j]*si
                               A[k,j] = A[k,j]*co - store *si
                           store = A[i,i]
                           A[i,i] = A[i,i]*co*co + 2.0*A[i,j]*co*si +A[j,j]*si*si  # Eq. (3.58)
                           A[j,j] = A[j,j]*co*co - 2.0*A[i,j]*co*si +store *si*si  # Eq. (3.59)
                           A[i,j] = 0.0                                            # Eq. (3.60)
                           for k in range(0,n):
                                store  = U[k,j]
                                U[k,j] = U[k,j]*co - U[k,i]*si  # Eq. (3.66)
                                U[k,i] = U[k,i]*co + store *si  # Eq. (3.67)
         info = -t # in case no convergence is reached set info to a negative value "-t"
    return ev,U,t

n = int(input("Enter the matrix size: "))

A = np.zeros((n, n))

for i in range(n):
    A[i] = input().split(" ")

MatrixA = np.array(A)
print("A= ")
print(A)
for i in range(A.shape[0]):
    row = ["{}*x{}".format(A[i, j], j + 1) for j in range(A.shape[1])]

# Jacobi-method
ev,U,t = Jacobi(A)
print ("JACOBI METHOD: Number of rotations = ",t)
print ("Eigenvalues  = ",ev)
print ("Eigenvectors = ")
print (U)
```

Comment: You should debug this on a small (say the 2x2 `array([[1, 2], [3,4]])`) matrix, where you can run the calculation by hand. And maybe you will get more help on codereview.stackexchange

Comment: @Demi-Lune The Jacobi method only works for symmetric matrices so it would have to be '''[[1,2], [2,3]]'''